# Exclude transitive dependency in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, transitive-dependency

During build via Gradle I got this

```
POM relocation to an other version number is not fully supported in Gradle : xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2 relocated to xml-apis:x
ml-apis:1.0.b2.
Please update your dependency to directly use the correct version 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2'.
Resolution will only pick dependencies of the relocated element. Artifacts and other metadata will be ignored.
```

Batik 1.7 was used in project.
This version of Batik uses Xalan 2.6.0, which has dependency on xml-apis 2.0.2, which was relocated.

How to resolve this transitive dependency?

Answer (score 8):

**Option 1:**

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2'
    }
}
```

See [ResolutionStrategy.force(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

**Option 2:**

```
dependencies {
    compile "batik:batik:$batikVersion", {
       exclude group: "xml-apis", module: "xml-apis"
    }
    compile "xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2"
}
```

See [ModuleDependency.exclude(Map)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude%28java.util.Map%29)

Comment: In your option 2, you are excluding a specific version and including the version which is needed. My doubt is that, in this case 'x' jar uses 'y' jar so exclude and include our wanted version. But let's say 'x' jar uses 'y' jar which again used 'z' jar, then what should I do if I want specific version of 'z' jar?

Comment: "In your option 2, you are excluding a specific version" That's incorrect. I'm not specifying a version. So it excludes all versions (regardless of x/y or x/y/z scenario). So then I can explicitly choose the version I want, knowing its not included by batik (or any of batik's transitive dependencies)